# HI I am trying to build ark from ionic angular app getting errors during build

Tags: java, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build ark from ionic angular app (on bitbucket pipelines I,e server) using command ionic Cordova build android and during building java compilation is failing

```
image: node:10.14.1
 pipelines:
   default:
     - step:
         script:
            npm install -g ionic cordova
            npm install 
-          - apt-get update
-          - yes | add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
-          - yes | apt install  oracle-java8-installer
-          - apt-get install zip unzip
-          - wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
-          - unzip sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
-          - mkdir android-sdk
-          - mv tools android-sdk/tools
-          - yes | android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27"
-          - yes | android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
-          - wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-bin.zip -P /tmp
-          - unzip -d /opt/gradle /tmp/gradle-*.zip
-          - ls /opt/gradle/gradle-5.0
-          - export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.0
-          - export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
-          - export ANDROID_HOME=android-sdk
-          - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
-          - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
-          - gradle --version
            - npm install
            - ionic Cordova build android

/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExposedJsApi.java:22: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.JSONException;
               ^
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExposedJsApi.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    public String exec(int bridgeSecret, String service, String action, String callbackId, String arguments) throws JSONException, IllegalAccessException;
                                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class JSONException
  location: interface ExposedJsApi
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: error: package android.annotation does not exist
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
                         ^
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:26: error: package android.webkit does not exist
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
```

Comment: does the same yaml work on your localhost setup?

Comment: @nkshio ...... i followed the same steps on mac terminal except downloading java from oracle.......